# How can I correctly set up UiAutomatorViewer to inspect elements for testing Android apps with Appium?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, appium, python-appium

When running `uiautomatorviewer`, I am getting the following `NullPointerException` error:

[image]

I have installed and set up Appium following the setup process and set up environment variables for ANDROID_HOME and the Android SDK. The `uiautomatorviewer` command is using a Path user variable that points to the directory `Sdk/tools/bin`, where the `uiautomatorviewer.bat` file is located. From everything I've read online, running this executable should open up the UiAutomatorViewer application, so I can inspect elements on my Android app. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54523635/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The correct fix for this issue:

**Java SDKs 9 and 10 do not work with Appium and the Android SDK**. You have to uninstall the Java SDK for the more recent version and install the Java 8 SDK instead.

#### For Linux

Follow this process:

1. `brew cask uninstall java # uninstall java9`
2. `brew tap caskroom/versions`
3. `brew cask install java8 # install java8`
4. `touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg # without this file, error will occur on next step`
5. `brew cask install android-sdk`

#### For Windows

1. Open Add or Remove Programs menu and uninstall Java 9/10.
2. Install Java 8 using the [installer](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can you just reconnect the device and restart it and the `uiautomator`? But make sure the test script is not running in the background. Or you can kill the `adb server` and restart it again.

You can go and check if you forgot any steps in *[UIAutomatorViewer Tutorial: Inspector for Android Testing](https://www.guru99.com/uiautomatorviewer-tutorial.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

I was using *[uiautomatorviewer](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator#inspect-ui)* with corretto-11.0.13 (after some edits in a .bat file) until I upgraded Android Studio to [2021.2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Chipmunk) (to solve another issue in the Android build) and the problem didn't disappear. Moreover, more problems appeared. *uiautomatorviewer* didn't work again.

I rolled back to Android Studio 4.1.1, restored a change done in the *find_java.bat* file, and it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

You must add the following **Android/sdk/tools/bin/** in the system environment variable.
If you are using window os, you can do it like following:

1. Right-click on ‘This PC’ and select Properties.
2. Click 'Advanced system settings' and select ‘Environmental Variables’ option
3. Under the 'System variables", select 'Path' and click 'Edit'
4. Click 'New" and add the path of  **Android/sdk/tools/bin/**  in the like

   > C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin

then you will be able to run uiautomatorviewer command in the command prompt.

The alternative way is to open command prompt in  **Android/sdk/tools/bin/** folder and then run uiautomatorviewer command.

Comment: Did you read the question? I stated in my question that I've already set up the environment variables for the Android SDK. Also, you can see in my screenshot that I ran the `uiautomator` command and it had an error output. If I hadn't set up the environment variable correctly, it would have just been a "command not found" error. Pay attention to the question